# in scala type linearization explain first step in algorithm

Tags: scala

I saw this [explanation](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/)

Where first step is:

> "start building a list of types, the first element is the type we’re
>   linearizing right now,"

however the result of this is:

```
// start with D1:
B with C with <D1>
```

I don't get it.  We start with D1 why is it in `<>` at all? why is `C with D1` and not `D1 with B`.  I don't get whats going on there, can you please explain?

Comment: try posting on a site where such questions are not off topic, might help get some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to read the example a few times. I infer from the text elsewhere that the <> (diamonds) is a way to highlight the type we are looking at. So the type is

```
<D1>
```

`D1` is defined as

```
class D1 extends B with C
```

Since `D1` is lowest in the hierarchy, it is shown last.

```
B with C with <D1>
```

The rest of the steps are expansions of `B` and `C`, and the subsequent linearization.

Overall, I think the author's example, in this case, is confusing. He is using Scala syntactic form to show a semantic process. While this can work quite well for demonstrating, for instance, the substitution principle, here it confounds syntax and semantics, instead of clarifying them.